# Blazor, Checkbox keep checked, event after StateHasChanged() method called

Tags: checkbox, data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this code :

```
@foreach (var item in list)
{
 <input type="checkbox" @onchange="@(e => HandleCheckChanged(e, item.Name))" checked="@item.IsChecked">
}

private async Task HandleCheckChanged(ChangeEventArgs e, string itemName)
{
   // do something ...
   StateHasChanged();
}
```

if I check a checkbox it calls the HandleCheckChanged and the **checkbox is checked**

 But if I **change the list items** the previews checked checkbox is **still checked** and is not updated based on the new list items.

for example suppose that I have a list of ordered numbers {1-20} I follow these steps : 
1 : list = GetAll().Where(c => c.Id < 10);
2 : I check the first checkbox (number 1) 
3 : list = GetAll().Where(c => c.Id >= 10); (list updated and state has changed) 
4 : the problem raises here , checkbox 11 is checked ??? but its value is false

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the renderer just sees the 'same' list of checkboxes and sees no reason to send an update.

A simple solution using `@key` to express that they are different items:

```
@foreach (var item in list)
{
 <input @key="item" type="checkbox" @onchange="@(e => HandleCheckChanged(e, item.Name))" checked="@item.IsChecked">
}
```

You do not have to call StatehasChanged() but it won't do any harm either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what @Henk said is correct and there is also other solution: 
 You can wrap your HTML input with `<EditForm Model='YourModel'>`. because whenever `EdtitForm.Model` changes, `EditForm.OnParametersSet` is excuted and `OnParametersSet` will call `StateHasChanged` to rerender the existing component.
[Blazor-university](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/) has good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
              <input type="checkbox" @bind="@IsChecked"/>
```